# I am debugging a program using gdb and I'm getting a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
const char* text = str->text;
```

This line of code is what is producing the error as found in gdb, it is in a function that displays a string.

```
Tokens* createTokens(String* str, char delimiter)
{
   int start_size = 1;
   Tokens* tokens = initTokens(start_size);
   int start = 0;
   cout << tokens->sz << endl;
   tokens->sz = 1;
   while (start < tokens->sz)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < str->sz; i++)
      {
          int end = find(str, delimiter, start);
          str = substr(str, start, end);
          addToken(tokens, str);
          start = end;
          tokens->sz ++;
      }
   }


   return tokens;
```

I believe this code is where the error originates from. I'm not sure where the problem is though. I'm a beginner programmer in a very hard intro C++ class so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing how `find` and `substr` are declared it's hard to say if you're passing the correct arguments. There are a couple of obvious errors in your code though. First you aren't checking the return value of `find` so if the string isn't found `substr` may fail. Second `str = substr(...)` changes `str` so it's pointing to the newly extracted string instead of the original string passed to the function. You also aren't checking for null pointer values, oops!

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking, from the beginning, everything that you believe is true about a piece of code.

In this case, check the values of str and then check str->text.

I believe str is set to NULL. You'll have to back-track that, by checking its value at earlier and earlier points in the program.

If you are lucky, your gdb can do reverse execution. See http://jayconrod.com/posts/28/tutorial-reverse-debugging-with-gdb-7 and https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Reverse-Execution.html